In Plotting Histogram graph, facing problem in ticks on x-axis
I have generated a histogram graph, graph looks good except the x-axis ticks which are not positioned middle of the bar and sometimes the ticks are randomly placed to the edges or center of the bar.
Histogram Graph - Screenshot
In the screenshot, ticks under the bars are randomly placed but I need ticks position should be placed exactly mid position under bar like 191.
def generate_histogram(data_dict):
    result_folder = 'graphs'
    if not os.path.exists(result_folder):
        os.makedirs(result_folder)
    pdf_file = os.path.join(result_folder, '{filename?_{timestamp}.pdf")
   
    with PdfPages(pdf_file) as pdf:
        for key, values in data_dict.items):
            plt.figure(figsize=(25, 20))
            n, bins, patches = plt.hist(values, bins=38, edgecolor="black" , alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.8, botton=0, label=key)
            if key.endswith("Width_in_ps'):
                key_value = "Width in ps"
            if key.endswith(Height_in_mV):
                key_value = "Height in mv"
            plt.xlabel(f' {key_valve}')
            plt.ylabel('Count')
            if key:
                t1 = key.replace("in_ps", ""), replace(" in_m", "")
            plt.title(t1)


            # Calculate tick positions for the y-axis
            max_count = int (max(n))
            # Set y-axis ticks to include 0 and the maximum count
            y_ticks = [0, max_count]
            plt.yticks(y_ticks)

            # Ensure unique x-axis tick values
            unique_values = np.unique(values)
            plt.xticks(unique_values, rotation=45)   #To rotate values on x-axis ticks use thisline

            # Annotate each bar with its count
            for i in range(len(patches)):
                if n[i] != 0:
                plt.text(patches[i].get_x) + patches[i].get_width() / 2, patches[i].get_height()/1,
                  str(int(n[i])), ha='center', color='black') # Centering count on top of the bar

            plt.tight_layout()
            pdt.savefig()
            plt.close()

    print(f"\033[92mPDF file '{pdf_file}' has been generated. \033[0m")`\

generate_histogram(data_dict)


Explicit bin edges
To ensure that the histogram bins go nicely aligned to your discrete values, you need to explicitly calculate bin edges away from these values. So, at positions 112.5, 113.5, ..., 217.5. Otherwise, some input values will fall into the same bucket.
Here is how it could look like:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generate some random test data, similar to the original question
np.random.seed(20240517)
values = np.random.choice(np.random.randint(113, 218, 15), 500)

# explicitly calculate bin edges away from the input values
unique_values = np.unique(values)
bins = np.arange(min(unique_values) - 0.5, max(unique_values) + 1)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
counts, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(values, bins=bins, edgecolor="black", alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.8)

# Calculate tick positions for the y-axis
max_count = int(max(counts))
# Set y-axis ticks to include 0 and the maximum count
y_ticks = [0, max_count]
plt.yticks(y_ticks)

# Ensure unique x-axis tick values
plt.xticks(unique_values, rotation=45)

# Annotate each bar with its count
for count, patch in zip(counts, patches):
    if count != 0:
        plt.text(patch.get_x() + patch.get_width() / 2, patch.get_height(),
                 f'{count:.0f}\n', ha='center', va='center', color='black')

plt.margins(x=0.03)  # less whitespace left and right
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


The original bins
With bins=38, the bin edges are distributed evenly between the first and last value, supposing the input are reals, ignoring integer edges.
As such, e.g. 185 and 186 (in the new example) are put into the same bucket.
The plot below shows the bin edges via red lines, and the value positions in blue.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20240517)
values = np.random.choice(np.random.randint(113, 218, 15), 500)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
counts, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(values, bins=38, edgecolor="black", alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.8)

# Calculate tick positions for the y-axis
max_count = int(max(counts))
# Set y-axis ticks to include 0 and the maximum count
y_ticks = [0, max_count]
plt.yticks(y_ticks)

# Ensure unique x-axis tick values
unique_values = np.unique(values)
plt.xticks(unique_values, rotation=45)

# Annotate each bar with its count
for count, patch in zip(counts, patches):
    if count != 0:
        plt.text(patch.get_x() + patch.get_width() / 2, patch.get_height(),
                 f'{count:.0f}\n', ha='center', va='center', color='black')

# show where the bin edges are located
for edge in bin_edges:
    plt.axvline(edge, color='r', ls='--')
# show where the values are located
for x in unique_values:
    plt.axvline(x, color='b', ls='--', lw=0.5)

plt.margins(x=0.02)  # less whitespace left and right
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


Seaborn's histplot with discrete=True
Alternatively, you can use seaborn's histplot with discrete=True, which will calculate the bin edges taking the integer values into account.
Matplotlib's new bar_label() function can help to position the labels (although currently it lacks an option to skip empty bars).
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20240517)
values = np.random.choice(np.random.randint(113, 218, 15), 500)
unique_values = np.unique(values)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
ax = sns.histplot(values, discrete=True)

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0],
             labels=[f'{bar.get_height()}' if bar.get_height() > 0 else "" for bar in ax.containers[0]])
ax.set_xticks(unique_values)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)

ax.margins(x=0.02)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



You just have to change this line:
plt.xticks(bins, rotation=45)


Maybe try to manually compute the xticks values so that it matches your histogram bins. You need to compute the center of each bin and place it on your graph with something like :
bin_centers = 0.5 * (bins[:-1] + bins[1:])
plt.xticks(bin_centers, np.round(bin_centers, 0))

